# How to Enable Qualcomm Diagnostic Mode

Tags: android-studio, adb, xiaomi, qualcomm, 3g-network

I have Sunmi T2 mini and currently experiencing some 3G and 4G connectivity issues with the device. 
I would like to use  QXDM Pro to capture logs from the device.

The steps that I have followed are as follows:

```
1. Enable Developer Mode on the device 
2. Enable USB debugging on the device.
```

In android studio I have run the following ADB functions:

```
1. adb shell
2. su
3. setprop sys.usb.config diag,adb
```

In the device can see that the device has been detected and the port is active, see image below:
[image: Device Manager]

However, when trying to connect to the device using QXDM pro I get the following screen below:

[image: Device Selection in QXDM Pro]

From the image above I am not able to connect to the device